# Unexpected behavior with biblatex-chicago and references with more than three authors

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I have an unexpected behavior using `biblatex-chicago` and references with more than three authors.

An MWE of my TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,uniquelist]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{ref}

\begin{document}
\autocite{batty2007iq}

\autocite{batty2007premorbid}

\autocite{batty2009iq_early}

\autocite{batty2009iq_socio}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and my bib:

```
  @article{batty2007iq,
  title={IQ in early adulthood and later cancer risk: cohort study of one million Swedish men},
  author={Batty, G. David and Wennerstad, Karin Modig and Smith, George Davey and Gunnell, David and Deary, Ian J. and Tynelius, Per and Rasmussen, Finn},
  journal={Annals of Oncology},
  volume={18},
  number={1},
  pages={21--28},
  year={2007},
  publisher={European Society for Medical Oncology}
  }

  @article{batty2007premorbid,
  title={Premorbid (early life) IQ and Later Mortality Risk: Systematic Review},
  author={Batty, G. David and Deary, Ian J. and Gottfredson, Linda S.},
  journal={Annals of Epidemiology},
  volume={17},
  number={4},
  pages={278--288},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Elsevier}
  }

  @article{batty2009iq_early,
  title={IQ in Early Adulthood and Mortality By Middle Age: Cohort Study of 1 Million Swedish Men},
  author={Batty, G. David and Wennerstad, Karin Modig and Smith, George Davey and Gunnell, David and Deary, Ian J. and Tynelius, Per and Rasmussen, Finn},
  journal={Epidemiology},
  volume={20},
  number={1},
  pages={100--109},
  year={2009},
  publisher={LWW}
  }

  @article{batty2009iq_socio,
  title={IQ in Early Adulthood, Socioeconomic Position, and Unintentional Injury Mortality by Middle Age: A Cohort Study of More Than 1 Million Swedish Men},
  author={Batty, G. David and Gale, Catharine R. and Tynelius, Per and Deary, Ian J. and Rasmussen, Finn},
  journal={American Journal of Epidemiology},
  volume={169},
  number={5},
  pages={606--615},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
  }
```

Above code results in:

[image]

which is not what I want. However, if I comment \autocite{batty2007iq} or \autocite{batty2009iq_early}, I get the result I want (except the commented reference, obviously), e.g:

[image]

I do not understand why my code results in "Batty et al. 2007" and "Batty et al. 2009" and not "Batty, Wennerstad, et al. 2007" and "Batty, Wennerstad, et al. 2009". For a reader it is hard to distinguish the exact reference.

To be clear, what I want is this:

> (Batty, Wennerstad, et al. 2007)
>
> (Batty, Deary, and Gottfredson 2007)
>
> (Batty, Wennerstad, et al. 2009)
>
> (Batty, Gale, et al. 2009)

Is that possible?

Edit: I forgot one thing. I only want two names in the cite if the reference otherwise would be unclear. I cite many "more than three authors" papers, but for those papers (Lastname et al. Year) is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a way I would have actually expected the output you want from the disambiguation feature (especially after reading §4.11.4.2 *Lists of Names (`uniquelist`)*, p. 237-238 of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), there we always get unambiguous *et al*s).

This issue has been addressed by the Biber developer. In version 2.7 the output should be as expected. See [`biblatex` issue #336](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/336), as well as [`biblatex` issue #487](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/487), which was sparked by [Setting uniquelist=true should print second author in all corresponding lists of names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330944/)

---

For pre-2.7 versions of Biber. We need to find a work-around.
Enter a bit of cheating: `mincitenames` can be set on a per-entry basis, so I added it to `batty2007iq` and `batty2009iq_early` via the `options` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,uniquelist=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{batty2007iq,
  title={IQ in early adulthood and later cancer risk: cohort study of one million Swedish men},
  author={Batty, G. David and Wennerstad, Karin Modig and Smith, George Davey and Gunnell, David and Deary, Ian J. and Tynelius, Per and Rasmussen, Finn},
  journal={Annals of Oncology},
  volume={18},
  number={1},
  pages={21--28},
  year={2001},
  publisher={European Society for Medical Oncology},
  options = {mincitenames=2},
}

@article{batty2007premorbid,
  title={Premorbid (early life) IQ and Later Mortality Risk: Systematic Review},
  author={Batty, G. David and Deary, Ian J. and Gottfredson, Linda S.},
  journal={Annals of Epidemiology},
  volume={17},
  number={4},
  pages={278--288},
  year={2002},
  publisher={Elsevier},
}

@article{batty2009iq_early,
  title={IQ in Early Adulthood and Mortality By Middle Age: Cohort Study of 1 Million Swedish Men},
  author={Batty, G. David and Wennerstad, Karin Modig and Smith, George Davey and Gunnell, David and Deary, Ian J. and Tynelius, Per and Rasmussen, Finn},
  journal={Epidemiology},
  volume={20},
  number={1},
  pages={100--109},
  year={2003},
  publisher={LWW},
  options = {mincitenames=2},
}

@article{batty2009iq_socio,
  title={IQ in Early Adulthood, Socioeconomic Position, and Unintentional Injury Mortality by Middle Age: A Cohort Study of More Than 1 Million Swedish Men},
  author={Batty, G. David and Gale, Catharine R. and Tynelius, Per and Deary, Ian J. and Rasmussen, Finn},
  journal={American Journal of Epidemiology},
  volume={169},
  number={5},
  pages={606--615},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{batty2007iq}

\autocite{batty2007premorbid}

\autocite{batty2009iq_early}

\autocite{batty2009iq_socio}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Batty, Wennerstad, et al. 2007) (Batty, Deary, and Gottfredson 2007) (Batty, Wennerstad, et al. 2009) (Batty, Gale, et al. 2009)]

Comment: I'm really not sure how these disambiguation features are supposed to work and certainly very hesitant to call this a bug, but maybe some of the `biblatex` maintainers has a look at this and can give some insight into this.

Comment: Thanks! Though not the ideal solution, this works. (I am not sure if I am supposed to mark this answer as a solution as it is not "permanent".)

Comment: @MattiasÖhman In what way is it not permanent? (It is ad-hoc, I will give you that.) You can accept the answer if you are content with it and if someone comes along with something better, accept the other, better answer.

Comment: Ok, sure, ad hoc. :-) It requires one to update the bib on a per-entry basis in a way that can become rather cumbersome if you often add/remove references, which really should not be necessary, as I see it. What I want is, I guess, what a journal would require.

Comment: @MattiasÖhman Yep. I was counting on you not having so many entries in your database that require this treatment. As I said, name disambiguation is quite complicated and `biblatex` does an awesome job at it. In that case the output might not be what you expect, but then just ask the maintainers (at [the github bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues)) if they can implement your wish.

Comment: Thanks! [Github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/336)

Answer (score 1):

Use the optional arguments for names:

```
\usepackage[authordate,uniquelist,maxnames=3,minnames=2]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

or if it should affect only the cite names:

```
\usepackage[authordate,uniquelist,maxcitenames=3,mincitenames=2]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

Comment: That could work. Unfortunately I guess that would force two names for all references. I only want two names if the reference otherwise would be unclear.