# Setting uniquelist=true should print second author in all corresponding lists of names

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

The `biblatex` manual presents the following example for `uniquelist=true` (see §4.11.4.2):

The three publications

```
Smith/Johnson/Doe 2005
Smith/Doe/Edwards 2005
Smith/Doe/Jones   2005
```

are disambiguated (regardless of `maxcitenames`) to

```
Smith, Johnson et al. 2005
Smith, Doe and Edwards 2005
Smith, Doe and Jones 2005
```

when citing with an author-year style.

**My problem**: When the last two publications have the same third author

```
Smith/Johnson/Doe 2005
Smith/Doe/Edwards 2005
Smith/Doe/Edwards 2005
```

the citations are printed as

```
Smith, Johnson et al. 2005
Smith et al. 2005a
Smith et al. 2005b
```

This can be reproduced with the MWE below.

**Expected output**:

```
Smith, Johnson et al. 2005
Smith, Doe et al. 2005a
Smith, Doe et al. 2005b
```

In my opinion, "Doe" should be part of the list because this explicitly *excludes* "Johnson" from the list of authors. Otherwise, the reader has to figure out that "Smith et al." does not refer to the publication with Johnson because … well, it's not obvious at least.

Is there a way to achieve this?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article {entry1,
author = {Smith and Johnson and Doe},
title = {Article 1},
year = 2005
}

@article {entry2,
author = {Smith and Doe and Edwards},
title = {Article 2},
year = 2005
}

@article {entry3,
author = {Smith and Doe and Edwards},
title = {Article 3},
year = 2005
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=authoryear-comp,
    maxcitenames=2,
    uniquelist=true]
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{entry1} \\
\textcite{entry2} \\
\textcite{entry3}
\vfill
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it is bug as it could be difficult to implement the "correct" (expected) result, but I made a bug report anyway: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/487

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, I never thought it is a bug. I think this is expected behavior which I just don't like. However, if this should be "fixed", I won't complain of course. Thank you for the report.

Comment: I think it may well be an edge case bug. It is tricky to deal with but it should be possible as biber has all the necessary machinery and data structures. Looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `biblatex` 3.7 and `biber` 2.7 from Sourceforge (they are the current development versions). This should be fixed now.