# How to install the development version of BibLaTeX (using MiKTeX on Windows)?

Tags: biblatex, miktex, installing, biber, updating

I know, this is most likely well documented and has been asked before, so probably I am just overwhelmed by the amount of available information on the issue. I'm trying to **install the development version of BibLaTeX** (and biber). <sub>(In a sense, this is a follow-up to my [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330944/37118)).</sub>

## Environment

- MiKTeX
- Windows 10

## What I did:

- Step 0: Update MiKTeX (as administrator and normal user); refresh FNDB.
- Step 1: Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/37118), I created a local texmf tree by creating the folder `localtexmf` on `C:` and running

  ```
  initexmf --register-root=c:\localtexmf
  initexmf --update-fndb
  initexmf --update-fndb --admin % probably irrelevant
  ```
- Step 2: Created `C:\localtexmf\bin` and added it to my `PATH` (before the MiKTeX installation folder), restarted system.
- Step 3: Downloaded the binary development version of biber [from Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/binaries/Windows/) and extracted `biber.exe` to `C:\localtexmf\bin`. (+ Updated FNDB.)

This seems to have been successful; when running biber on my document it reports

> INFO - This is Biber 2.7 (beta)

The problematic part is getting the development version of BibLaTeX to run, which should be explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2066/37118). However, the [development version of BibLaTeX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/development/) is not available as `dtx`/`ins` bundle but only as `tgz` or `tds.tgz`. In the linked answer, the instructions on `tds.tgz` are just "check README files" and "extract it to the right place". I tried to find the "right place", but without any success:

- Step 4a: Downloaded `biblatex-3.7.tds.tgz` and extracted `biblatex-3.7.tds.tgz/biblatex-3.7.tds.tar/` to the new local tree. Updated FNDB. Result: New version not recognized (still using version 3.6)
  [image: Copy]
- Step 4b: Trying to follow the "Semi-automatic installation" section from the README (included in the `tgz` archive). This refers to a `.tds.zip` file which I assume to be identical to my `.tds.tar` file. Then, 4b boils down to what I did in 4a.
- Step 4c: Trying to follow the "Manual installation" section from the README. This refers to a `.tar.gz` file which I assume to be identical to my `.tgz` file. Extracting the files as described in the README (steps 3–5 and 7) and updating the FNDB has the same effect as 4a.
- Step 4d: Analogous to step 4a, I tried to extract `biblatex-3.7.tgz/biblatex-3.7.tar` to the local tree (with and without the enclosing `biblatex` folder), without an effect.

Each time I installed/tried to install a new version of BibLaTeX, I deleted all intermediate files created in the by the previous run of LaTeX (to avoid using an old `bcf` file). I suppose my directory structure is somehow wrong or that I downloaded the wrong archives. The full error message biber throws is:

> INFO - Reading 'document.bcf'
>
> ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.2, expected version 3.3. This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex (3.6) versions are incompatible.

I *know* that the versions are incompatible, but **how can I install BibLaTeX 3.7 (the current development version)?**

---

**Update:** A very helpful [comment by Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331374/how-to-install-the-development-version-of-biblatex-using-miktex-on-windows?noredirect=1#comment812064_331374) made me realize that there is something wrong with how my roots are ordered: `kpsewhich --all biblatex.sty` returns my `C:\localtexmf` root as second, after a MiKTeX-maintained root in `C:\Users\...`. However, in the MiKTeX Options I cannot move my local tree up (the button is grayed out). According to [bug #1952](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/1952/) this is by design, but then I don't understand how to make use of local trees. (I added the tree as non-administrator and are trying to move it as non-administrator. I also tried to move it as administrator, or to add and then move it as administrator.)

[image: Trees]

Comment: You need first to unpack the tds.tgz, this should give you a tar-file. tar is again an "archive" format, so you need to unpack the tar too so that you get "normal" folders, (tex/latex etc). These you can then copy to your local texmf. Btw: You can rename the biber.exe e.g. to biberdev.exe and copy it to your normal bin-folder. Then adapt the editor to use biberdev instead of biber.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is what I did in step 4a.

Comment: No, you did put the tar-file in your local texmf. But tar is like zip a container, you need to unpack it first. Do the extraction in some empty temp folder and then copy the tex/latex and bibtex and biber folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did not put the tar file in the texmf folder. Sorry if my question wrongly suggests this. I was hoping to make this clear with "extracted biblatex-3.7.tds.tgz/biblatex-3.7.tds.tar/": I extracted the `tar` file, which is in the `tgz`file, to the tree.

Comment: Then you perhaps extracted it in the wrong level. I always do the extraction in a temp-folder and then copy the `tex` folder and the others to the local texmf-tree (in your case `c:\localtexmf`) -- much less confusing. Btw: do you update the FNDB as admin or user?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added a screenshot of the files I copied. Looks correct, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. If it doesn't work you either didn't update the FNDB correctly (run `initexmf -u` and `initexmf --admin -u`), or you have a version which is found first (check the log-file, run `kpsewhich --all biblatex.sty`. Also delete before your test old .bcf, .aux, .blg-files to avoid that they interfere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's interesting: `kpsewhich --all biblatex.sty` actually points to `C:/Users/CL/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/...` instead of my local tree. In fact, when I view the "Roots" in MiKTeX Options, my local tree comes after that (and another) MiKTex-maintained root. However, I cannot move it "Up", the button is grayed out.

Comment: Ok, as a workaround I uninstalled biblatex 3.6. Now the development version from the local tree is used. Still, I wonder why it is not possible/why I'm not supposed to move my local tree before the MiKTeX-maintained tree, making removing the stable version unnecessary.

Comment: I don't have a multiuser installation so I can't test how it handles the root order, but probably you can install the stable version with the package manager admin.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Exactly, this is possible. But if the local tree could be given priority over the MiKTeX-maintained tree, then it would not be necessary to remove the stable version from the MiKTeX tree before using the development version from the local tree. As far as I understand local trees, not having to touch the "main" tree when modifying packages is the key advantage of using a separate local tree. This advantage is lost if I have to remove the stable package before I can use the new package.

Comment: As I said I have a single-user-installation. There the roots `UserConfig` and `UserData` are first, then my local roots, then `UserInstall`. So `UserInstall` is *behind* my local roots. I can't tell you if there is an installation option for multi user system to get something similar -- you could try a new bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer FYI, I filed a new [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2534/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, this were the required steps on my system:

- [Create a local texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/37118). The gist is, create the folder `C:\localtexmf` and a subfolder `tex` and then run

  ```
  initexmf --register-root=c:\localtexmf
  initexmf --update-fndb
  ```
- Open MiKTeX Options and go to the "Roots" tab. Check the "Show MiKTeX-maintained root directories" box. Your local tree should be *before* "UserInstall".

  1. If your local tree *is* before "UserInstall", you can skip to the next bullet point.
  2. If you can use the "Up" button to move your local tree before "UserInstall", then do so.
  3. Else, your setup probably looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuFnP.png), i.e. "UserInstall" and "UserConfig" point to the same path. In this case, you [need to separate "UserInstall" and "UserConfig"](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2534/). To this end, set an environment variable `MIKTEX_USERINSTALL` that points to the new "UserInstall" path. I chose `C:\Users\CL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\install`.
  4. Run `initexmf --update-fndb --verbose`. Now, the local texmf directory should be listed before UserInstall but after UserConfig and UserData.
  5. Run `kpsewhich --all biblatex.sty`. This will probably point to a file in your UserConfig tree (in my case: `C:\Users\CL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex`). I suppose that this should not be the case but is an artifact of separating UserConfig and UserInstall after the fact. Delete that `biblatex` directory and update FNDB.
- Download the [development version of BibLaTeX from Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/development/). Choose the file with the `tds.tgz` extension (e.g. `biblatex-3.7.tds.tgz`).
- Open the `tds.tgz` file. It contains a `tds.tar` file. Copy the contents of the `tds.tar` file to your local texmf directory:
  [image: Copying the files]
- Run `initexmf --update-fndb --verbose` and then `kpsewhich --all biblatex.sty`. This should point to `biblatex.sty` in your local texmf directory.
- Don't forget to use the matching (development) version of biber.

---

A remark on step 5 under the second bullet point. As the local texmf tree has precedence over UserInstall (if MiKTeX is set up correctly), it is usually not necessary to remove the old/stable version of a package before copying a new version to the local texmf tree. The reason why the `biblatex` directory needs to be deleted in step 5 is because after separating UserInstall and UserConfig, the files (wrongly?) remain in UserConfig. Packages that are installed after the trees have been separated end up in UserInstall and don't need to be removed manually when another version from the local tree is to be used.

[Christian Schenk suggests](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2534/#b28f) to move the contents of UserConfig to UserInstall when separating the trees. This should make deleting the `biblatex` folder obsolete.

Comment: Many thanks to Ulrike Fischer and Christian Schenk for their support in figuring this out!