Using defbibsetentry with BibLaTex (Biber) and sorting ,,none'' doesn't actually sort by Text appearance
it's me again.
I just switched from using Natbib to BibLaTeX for my citation, using Biber, because I need a citation that looks like this[1a,b] (just in superscript).
And I have managed to do that by using the command \defbibsetentry.
However, I want my bibliography to be sorted by appearance, which is why I set sorting=none.
But the defbibsetentry does not appear in that order.
Below I have attached the used code.
When compiling it gives a ghostscripterror, however that is due to the fact that there is no image included, which is an easy fix and should not be the reason for the problem encountered.
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totocnumbered, ]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[crop=off, runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,sorting=none,hyperref=true,autocite=superscript,subentry]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\mkbibbracketsuperscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{%
    \mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbracketsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \let\multicitesubentrydelim=\supercitesubentrydelim
   \let\multiciterangedelim=\superciterangedelim
   \let\multicitesubentryrangedelim=\supercitesubentryrangedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\defbibentryset{WibergSchmuck}{wibergAnorganischeChemie2017a,schmuckBasisbuchOrganischeChemie2018}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \ifpdf\else
        \@ifpackageloaded{preview}{
            \ifPreview
                \RemoveFromHook{shipout/firstpage}[hyperref]
                \RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[hyperref]
                \RemoveFromHook{shipout/lastpage}[bookmark]
            \fi
        }{}
    \fi    
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello World.
I'm gonna cite a single Book first.\cite{perezAdvancesOganometallicChemistry2018}
Now I want the set.\cite{wibergAnorganischeChemie2017a,schmuckBasisbuchOrganischeChemie2018}
And finally, another single citation.\cite{friebolinUndZweidimensionaleNMRSpektroskopie2011}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

Following is the Text I recieve when compiling the code above (PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + PDF Anzeigen).
The issue, as you can easily see, is that instead of going in the right order of 1, then 2, then 3 by appearance, the numbering is suddenly different and I can neither explain why nor fix that.

I hope someone can help me out here, as I have no Idea how to fix that issue.
Added below is the code with auto-pst-pdf removed, just to show that I still get the same error.
I chose to include that package because I wanted to make sure that the sample still worked how I needed it to work in the main document, and I didn't expect it to make a difference.
Using the biblatex-examples.bib library file in a further update I made the MWE below usable by everyone.
I picked references at random, as it shouldn't matter.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totocnumbered, ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,sorting=none,hyperref=true,autocite=superscript,subentry]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\mkbibbracketsuperscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{%
    \mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbracketsuperscript]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \let\multicitesubentrydelim=\supercitesubentrydelim
   \let\multiciterangedelim=\superciterangedelim
   \let\multicitesubentryrangedelim=\supercitesubentryrangedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\defbibentryset{WesfahlAksin}{westfahl:space,aksin}

\begin{document}

Hello World.
I'm gonna cite a single Book first.\cite{angenendt}
Now I want the set.\cite{westfahl:space,aksin}
And finally, another single citation.\cite{bertram}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

If I compile the code, I get the same exact result.
It also doesn't seem to change what kind of file I cite.
In my original document I cited normal papers of the article type, which is where I encountered that issue first.


there is absolutly no reason why a question about biblatex load the auto-pst-pdf package. So simply remove it from your example. On the other side, without your bib file nobody can test your example.

@UlrikeFischer I understand what you're saying, I just hoped that by including the auto-pst-pdf I could make sure that if I did find a fix in the MWE, that fix would not introduce further issues into my main document due to some incompatibility with auto-pst-pdf. I have updated the post with a MWE without auto-pst-pdf. Removing that did not change the underlying issue. I have also added a wetransfer of the three files, Tex-, Bib- and PDF-File.

there is no need for external files. Either put a few entries into your questions, or use entries from biblatex-examples.bib.

@UlrikeFischer I have further updated the MWE to only include references from the example package. It does not appear to change anything. Putting \defbibsetentry right before the point at which I cite the 2 papers, so in the middle of the text, does not change anything either.

I opened an issue https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1405

@UlrikeFischer thank you. That at least means my code is correct, I guess.

@UlrikeFischer I have tried updating both Biber and Biblatex to their respective development versions (following this guide https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331374/how-to-install-the-development-version-of-biblatex-using-miktex-on-windows), however it doesn't work. I realize it's a different issue but when using both development versions, I get the Error that my Biber Version 2.21  is incompatible with my BibLaTeX (2.21) Version. Are you aware of anything I can do about that, so I can at least try and get it to work?

Sorry I didn't try yet, but as the issue only mentions a biber fix I would try the dev-biber with the current biblatex and not with the dev-biblatex. Beside this: according to the comment of moewe in the issue your problem isn't resolved yet, so you have to wait anyway.

@UlrikeFischer I just noticed in the Issue you opened that it should now be fixed. I still have trouble installing the development version, I guess that is to be expected with significantly fewer coding- and computer-knowledge. However, I did try your recommendation, tried both the release version of biblatex and the development version, and both give the same error. But the compatibility matrix does imply, that Biber 2.21 should be compatible with Biblatex 3.21, or at least my logic would say it should, as 2.20 and 3.20 are compatible. Should I open another question?

I downloaded the 64bit binary from https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/binaries/Windows/, (I'm on windows), unpacked the zip which contains a biber.exe. I renamed that to biberdev.exe and put it in some folder which is in my path. Then I compiled your example with pdflatex, biberdev, pdflatex, pdflatex and the bib looks fine. https://i.sstatic.net/vDr5nuo7.png

@UlrikeFischer I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I tried both MWEs from the opened issue on github. When I just cite the entryset with \cite{WestfahlAksin} I get the correct order, when citing either of the two papers or both the ordering is wrong again. I tried a new document, have completely reinstalled MikTex, I don't see what I'm doing wrong. It also doesn't seem to matter whether I use cite or autocite, but I did copy the MWE word for word to make sure I didn't mess anything up. I saved the dev version as biberdev.exe, and used biberdev % in the TeXMaker setup

Show the log-file and the blg-file of your example above.

@UlrikeFischer please disregard what I said. I made sure to check one last thing, downloaded the Biber Development Version again, now it works. So the issue was entirely stupid, preventable and on my side.
